# How to make block title words themable in D6

Tags: blocks, theming

I need to have my block title for Newsletter Signup block appear like this:

Sign up for mail

Note: Sign up = red colored font
for mail = blue colored font

Please help, I know how to override a block.tpl.php file, but I am not sure what my code would be to separate the word groups and add a div or span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty in your block.tpl.php:

```
<?php
  if ($block->subject=='Sign up for mail') {
    $block->subject='<span class="red">Sign up</span> <span class="blue">for mail</span>';
  }
?>
```

And in your .css file:

```
.blue {
   color: blue;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Would this go in my general block.tpl.php file or in a specific one for that block?

block.tpl.php right now show:
<?php if ($block->subject): ?>
<div class="title-wrapper-theme">
   <h2 class="title block-title"><?php print $block->subject ?></h2>

Comment: Works! Put it in the specific block template, see here http://drupal.org/node/104319